# PHP convert similar names variables to json

Tags: php, json, merge

I'm getting via url querystring variables like:

myserver_state=1&myserver_running=2&myserver_mem=3

Currently i'm adding to an existing json like:

```
{
   "key1": "1",
   "key2": "2",
   "key3": "3",
   "myserver_state": "1",
   "myserver_running": "2",
   "myserver_mem": "3"
}
```

And i really want it like this:

```
{
   "key1": "1",
   "key2": "2",
   "key3": "3",
   "myserver": {
      "state": "1",
      "running": "2",
      "mem": "3"
   }
}
```

I'm using this to load them:

```
        $formdata = array(
          'state'=> $_POST['state'],
          'uassip'=> $_POST['uassip'],
          'uassipport'=> $_POST['uassipport'],
          'c_uacminrtpport'=> $_POST['c_uacminrtpport'],
          'c_uacmaxrtpport'=> $_POST['c_uacmaxrtpport'],
          'c_cps'=> $_POST['c_cps'],
          'c_totalcalls'=> $_POST['c_totalcalls'],
          'c_maxchannels'=> $_POST['c_maxchannels'],
          'c_duration'=> $_POST['c_duration'],
          'c_to'=> $_POST['c_to'],
          'c_uacxml'=> $_POST['c_uacxml']
        );

        echo "fromdata: <br>"; echo var_dump($formdata) .  "<br><hr>";
        if(file_put_contents('testconfig.json', json_encode($formdata) )) echo 'OK';
        else echo 'Unable to save data in "testconfig.json"';
```

Many thanks!

EDIT:

following comments i tried:

status.php?server1[current_state]=10

this actually works to:

```
    "c_uacxml": "telnyx-uac-invite-ok.xml",
    "server1": {
        "current_state": "10"
    }
}
```

Which is great, BUT, if i then want to add an element like this:
status.php?server1[current_mem]=1

This actually REPLACES the whole `server1`

```
    "c_uacxml": "telnyx-uac-invite-ok.xml",
    "server1": {
        "current_mem": "10"
    }
}
```

and i lose the already existing current_state

Comment: Make  another array then, put your stuff there and add that array to the main array as `myserver` node

Comment: How about `status.php?server1[current_state]=1&server1[current_mem]=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use multidimensional array within your URL like:

```
test.php?key1=1&key2=2&myserver[state]=1&myserver[running]=2&myserver[mem]=3
```

so easy script

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($_GET, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

will give you

```
{
    "key1": "1",
    "key2": "2",
    "myserver": {
        "state": "1",
        "running": "2",
        "mem": "3"
    }
}
```

of course, if required you can use also POST request with the same naming rules.

Answer (score 0):

in order to create a nested JSON object, you need to create an array within an array.

E.g.

```
$example = [
    'key1' => 'foo',
    'key2' => 'bar',
    'key3' => [
        'subkey1' => 'foo',
        'subkey2' => 'bar',
    ],
];
```

When running it through `json_encode()`, it will result in

```
{
  "key1": "foo",
  "key2": "bar",
  "key3": {
    "subkey1": "foo",
    "subkey2": "bar"
  }
}
```

Also it's not necessary to load form data like this –

```
$formdata = [
    'state' => $_POST['state'],
    'uassip' => $_POST['uassip'],
    'uassipport' => $_POST['uassipport'],
    'c_uacminrtpport' => $_POST['c_uacminrtpport'],
    'c_uacmaxrtpport' => $_POST['c_uacmaxrtpport'],
    'c_cps' => $_POST['c_cps'],
    'c_totalcalls' => $_POST['c_totalcalls'],
    'c_maxchannels' => $_POST['c_maxchannels'],
    'c_duration' => $_POST['c_duration'],
    'c_to' => $_POST['c_to'],
    'c_uacxml' => $_POST['c_uacxml'],
];
```

Since the `$_POST` already contains a structure that you are trying to recreate. You can simply assign the post data to a new varaible.

On another note, I highly recommend you to check out PSR PHP standards, they will greatly help to improve code readability and your code structure :) https://www.php-fig.org/psr/